# Can you create ios game center leaderboard sets after app goes live

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard

I have a bug in my iTunesConnect account. I get a warning message on the 'versions' page of my app which says "Leaderboard xxx is not a member of a leaderboard set attached to version 1.0"

This stops me from saving the versions page of my app and therefore submitting my app. All my leaderboards are part of a leaderboard set which i have attached to the version. I have already contacted Apple about this problem, Apple confirmed I have not done anything wrong in the set up of my app on itunesConnect, they have confirmed other developers are having the same problem and that this is a problem on Apples side which they are working on. It's been weeks and i need to submit my app, I can't afford to wait indefinitely for them to solve this.

I have found that removing all the leaderboards from sets (i.e. having individual leaderboards without any sets) removes the warning messages on the versions page and allows me to save my app. So i can now submit it if i wish. However, i have two questions i need answered before i can do this:

Question 1-Will I be able to put the leaderboards in sets after the app goes live?( i.e. when Apple eventually fix the bug)

Question 2- Will I be able to change the leaderboard Name of individual leaderboards after it goes live.

I have checked the details provided on this 'Game Centre Properties' page provided by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/GameCenterProperties/GameCenterProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726-CH29-SW15)

It does not mention whether you can change/create leaderboard sets after the app goes live.

It does mention that the Leaderboard Name can be edited "After one binary is approved", but this does not make clear if they are referring to case 1 or 2 as described below:

case 1-You have selected "Manually release this version" for your app, your app binary has been approved, this is the first binary to be approved. You have not yet chosen to release it on the app store yet(You Can definitely edit).

case 2-Your app is released on the app store. The binary on the app store is the first one to be approved. (Can you still edit?)

This is my first app that uses game centre, so I am not able to test this for myself.